# Единый метод обнаружения внешних и внутренних накопителей

Tags: android

Вопрос стоит так. Существует ли метод, которым можно обнаружить ссылки на внутреннюю и внешнюю(если есть) память, который будет работать на всех устройствах. Мне это нужно, что бы организовать сканирование телефона и карты памяти на наличие mp3 файлов(делаю что то типа плеера).

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() в большинстве случаев дает ссылку на внутреннюю память.

Comment: можете попробовать посмотреть все папки в /storage/emulated и mnt/ там будет много лишнего, но это можно отфильтровать по размеру и правам записи. Думаю надёжно будет скомбинировать се эти методы сразу.